# Siril stacking algorithm

Tags: astrophotography

I am looking at the tutorial page for the astrophotography image processing software "Siril".

I am trying to determine which stacking algorithm I should be using.

Based on the information on the [this](https://free-astro.org/index.php/Siril:Tutorial_stacking) page, it seems like there is no good default stacking algorithm.

Under each description it basically says "this algorithm is good for this limited special case", but it never really mention which algorithm is the safe bet for the common case.

Which one should I be choosing to say, stack 20 frames of a widefield shot of the milky way, in an effort to remove noise.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the descriptions they give (I haven't tried many of these), I'd bet that images of the type you're talking about would do well with the Average Stacking With Rejection using the Linear Fit Clipping algorithm. Widefield shots are likely to fall into the category of "images containing sky gradients with differing spatial distributions and orientations."